# How does a packet get to the destination on the same network

Tags: networking, routes, ip, ping, subnet

[image]

This shows a network of 3 workstations and a router. below is the routing table of PC 1

[image]

If PC1 sends a packet to PC 2. How would it get to the destination? 
As I have understood PC1 would refer its routing table, and broadcast the packet.For that which entry in the routing table would it make use of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the third entry in your routing table: 172.16.18.0/24 is routed through 172.16.18.1 which is local network interface. Thus the OS knows that packets to this network should be delivered through this interface.

Comment: Thank you. That explains it